# Unobtrusive Google Maps API Javascript in Rails View

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript, unobtrusive-javascript

I have this javascript code inside my app/views/people/show.html.erb. It uses google maps api v3. But the thing is that this is very obtrusive. What I wanted is that I want the js codes to be inside the coffeescript. And that I should still be able to pass the longitude/latitude values to reflect them in the map.

```
<% unless @person.addresses.blank? %>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {

      <%
        if @person.addresses.first.latitude.blank? && @person.addresses.first.longitude.blank?
          lat_long = @person.organization.latitude_longitude
        else
          address = @person.addresses.first
          lat_long = [address.latitude, address.longitude] 
        end

        lat = lat_long[0]
        long = lat_long[1]
      %>

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= lat %>, <%= long %>);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas_show'), mapOptions);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
      });
    }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>

  <div id="map_canvas_show"></div>

<% end %>

<h1>
  <%= @person.name %> <small><%= link_to(t('general.edit'), edit_person_path(@person)) %></small>
</h1>

<h3>
  <%= @person.organization_names(current_organization) %>
</h3>

<div>
  <%#= image_tag @person.fb_profile_pic_large %>
</div>

<div class="sfield field_group">
  <div class="ls"><%= t('.addresses')%></div>
  <% @person.addresses.each do |address| %>
    <div class="rs"><%= address.address %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="sfield field_group">
  <div class="ls"><%= t('.phone_numbers')%></div>
  <% @person.phone_numbers.each do |phone_number| %>
    <div class="rs field_group"><%= phone_number.phone_number %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="sfield field_group">
  <div class="ls"><%= t('.offices')%></div>
  <% @person.office_names.each do |office_name| %>
    <div class="rs"><%= office_name %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML5 data-* attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) for this. See also the [ujs section](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript) of rails guide.

```
<div id="map_canvas_show" data-lat="<%= lat %>" 
                          data-long="<%= long %>" />
```

Then in jQuery you can use something like to get the coordinates:

```
var map_canvas = $('#map_canvas_show'); 
var lat = map_canvas.data('lat');
var lng = map_canvas.data('long');
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
```